# Capturar y registrar fecha actual en campo disable

Tags: php

necesito capturar la fecha actual en un campo que no se puede escribir y luego registrar esa fecha en la base de datos.

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" disabled="true" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
```

Pero al registrar en la base de datos no lo guarda. Pero sil e quito el disabled="true" lo guarda pero entonces en el campo se puede escribir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes cambiar el `disabled="true"` por `readonly="readonly"`

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó

Comment: te recomiento colocar un campo hidden y el otro campo readonly a modo que te cambie la fecha por el inspector de los navegadores